# Laravel/faker using invalid column names

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I'm running a Laravel 5.4 project created just three days ago.

I have this in my `ModelFactory.php`:

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\Definition::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
$tag = "tag";
$category = "cat";

return [
    'name' => $faker->words,
    'description' => $faker->realText,
    'tags' => $tag,
    'price' => $faker->numberBetween(500, 50000),
    'category' => $category
];
});
```

And in my `DatabaseSeeder.php`'s `run()`:

```
DB::table('definitions')->truncate();
factory(Definition::class, 200)->create();
```

But when I run `db:seed`, i keep getting:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table definitions has no column named 0 (SQL: insert into "definitions" ("0", "1", "2") select quia as "0", No, there were no arches left, and all dripping wet, cross, and uncomfortable. The first thing
>      I've got totag' (Alice had no reason to be ashamed of yourself for asking such a rule at processions;. as "1",
>     1302 as "2" union all select cat as "0", 2017-03-17 10:51:53 as "1", 2017-03-17 10:51:53 as "2" uni
>     on all select ? as "0", ? as "1", ? as "2" union all select ? as "0", ? as "1", ? as "2" union all select ? as "0",
>      ? as "1", ? as "2" union all select ? as "0", ? as "1", ? as "2" union all select ? as "0", ? as "1", ? as "2")

My table schema:

```
Schema::create('definitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->json("tags");
        $table->string('category');
        $table->unsignedInteger('x_id')->nullable(); 
        $table->nullableTimestamps();
```

I have `$guarded = [];` in my Definition class. I'm thinking maybe this is some faker bug, because I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 'description' => $faker->realText
```

This should be a function.

```
 'description' => $faker->realText()
```

Also

```
 'name' => $faker->words
```

should be a function, but it returns an array, not a string.
You could use

```
 'name' => $faker->name()
```

or

```
 'name' => $faker->sentence(3)
```

If you just want a 3 word sentence.